# How to insert file into a text box and let users edit it directly html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to implement a feature where a user accesses their file explorer, opens a .txt/.html file, and pastes it into a textarea box where they can then edit it and save it.

Is there a way to read the file and extract the contents into a textarea through an input `type="file"`?

What I have tried:

```html
<input id="insert" type="file" accept=".txt,.html" />
<textarea id="insert"></textarea>
```

Thank you so much! Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You can use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to get the contents and insert as value in the textarea

Comment: @Spectric Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FileReader API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

```js
var insert = document.getElementById("insert");
var insert1 = document.getElementById("insert1");
insert.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let file = insert.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function() {
    insert1.value = reader.result;
  };
})
```

```css
textarea{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<input id="insert" type="file" accept=".txt,.html" />
<br/><br/>
Upload a file and see the contents magically appear in the textarea below!
<br/><br/>
<textarea id="insert1"></textarea>
```